# A (slight) style loading delay with webpack

Tags: webpack

Just integrated webpack into my simple weather app and it's amazing... but there's one issue. When I open it up in the browser (chrome) there is a slight delay for the styles i.e. you can see the raw html for a few split seconds before the styles rush in. Here's my `webpack.config.js` file:

```js
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    mode: "development",
    entry: {
        main: "./src/scripts/app.js"
    },
    output: {
        filename: "bundle.js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist")
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin( { template: "./src/templates/index.html" } )
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            { test: /\.css$/, use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"] }
        ]
    },
    devServer: {
        static: {
            directory: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
        },
        compress: true,
        port: 3000,
        open: true
    }
}
```

As you can see I am using the `style-loader` and `css-loader` loaders. Is there any way to speed up the loading of the styles?

Comment below if you need any other info to suggest a solution.

Thanks.